# Maximizing the first Neumann eigenvalue on disks

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, eigenvalues, laplacian

Let $D^2$ be a smooth disk and for any Riemannian metric in $D$, let $\mu_1(g)$ be the first positive Neumann eigenvalue of the Laplacian on $(D, g)$. Li and Yau proved that

$$\mu_1(g) \operatorname{Area}(g) \leq 8\pi.$$

What is (if any) a maximizing metric on $D$ for the functional $g \mapsto \mu_1(g) \operatorname{Area}(g)$?

My guess is that there is no maximizing metric for the above functional. I think that considering spherical caps $B_{\pi - \delta}(N)$ of radius $\pi - \delta$ centered at the north pole of the unit sphere gives a maximizing sequence that doesn’t converge as $\delta \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there does not exist a maximising metric, and the sequence you identified does saturate the upper bound.

In order to see this, consider a slightly different problem. On $\mathbb S^2$, for $g_0$ the canonical round metric and for any Radon measure $m$ define the first non-trivial eigenvalue associated to this measure as
$$\lambda_1(m) := \inf\left\{\frac{\int_{\mathbb S^2} |\nabla_{g_0} f|^2 \, \mathrm d v_{g_0}}{\int_{\mathbb S^2} f^2 \, \mathrm d m} : f \in \mathrm C^\infty(\mathbb S^2), \int_{\mathbb S^2} f \, \mathrm d m = 0 \right\}.$$
You can refer to Sections 3 and 4 in ["Continuity of eigenvalues and shape optimisation for Laplace and Steklov problems"](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00039-021-00573-5) by A. Girouard, M. Karpukhin and J. Lagacé (Geom. Funct. Anal. 31, 513–561 (2021)) for a review on elementary properties of these eigenvalues. In particular, through a conformal change of variables you can bring the Laplace eigenvalue problem for any metric on the sphere to this form.

Let $\phi : (\mathbb D,g) \to \mathbb (S^2,g_0)$ be a conformal map from the disk into the sphere so that $g = \phi^* g_0$, and consider $\mathrm d m = \phi_* \mathrm d v_g$ the measure on $\mathbb S^2$ obtained by  pushing forward the $g$-volume measure on the disk. Then, we have from monotonicity of the Dirichlet energy under set inclusion, as well as its conformal invariance that
\begin{align*}
\mu_1(g) &= \inf \left \{\frac{\int_{\mathbb D} |\nabla_g f|^2 \, \mathrm d v_g}{\int_\mathbb D f^2 \, \mathrm d v_g } : f \in \mathrm C^\infty(\mathbb D), \int_{\mathbb D} f \, \mathrm d v_g = 0 \right \} \\
&= \inf \left \{\frac{\int_{\phi(\mathbb D)} |\nabla_{g_0} f|^2 \, \mathrm d v_{g_0}}{\int_{\phi(\mathbb D)} f^2 \, \mathrm d m } : f \in \mathrm C^\infty(\phi(\mathbb D)), \int_{\mathbb \phi(D)} f \, \mathrm d m = 0 \right \} \\
&\le \inf \left \{\frac{\int_{\mathbb S^2} |\nabla_{g_0} f|^2 \, \mathrm d v_{g_0}}{\int_{\mathbb S^2} f^2 \, \mathrm d m } : f \in \mathrm C^\infty(\mathbb S^2), \int_{\mathbb S^2} f \, \mathrm d m = 0 \right \} \\
&= \lambda_1(m).
\end{align*}
Now let us consider the problem of maximising the functional $m \mapsto \lambda_1(m) m(\mathbb S^2) =: \bar \lambda_1(m)$, keeping in mind that our previous computation gives us that $\mu_1(g) \operatorname{Area}(g) \le \bar \lambda_1(\phi_* \mathrm d v_g)$. Now, we know that for any non-atomic Radon measure $m$, $\bar \lambda_1(m) \le 8\pi$, and that the volume measure of the round metric attains that bound. Furthermore, by a theorem of Karpukhin and Stern (Theorem 1.4 in ["Min-max harmonic maps and a new characterization of conformal eigenvalues"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04086)) we know that any maximal measure is does not vanish on an open set, as this would contradict unique continuation. In particular, in conjunction with your example of a sequence of metrics on the disk saturating the $8\pi$ bound, no maximal metric can exist on the disk.

In fact, that argument can be extended to show that there are never maximal metrics for any Riemannian manifold with non-empty boundary, because it would imply again the existence of a maximal measure which vanishes on an open set.